# videojs Chapter menu css: how to expand box to line length?

Tags: css, video.js

I am trying to style the `videojs` CSS for the ChapterButton menu so that it expands to accommodate varying line lengths (e.g. no line wrapping). I can expand it to a fixed width but I need it to handle varying line lengths. Is there an easy way to do this? Am I looking at the right CSS rule?

**Existing CSS**

```
.vjs-menu-button-popup .vjs-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10em;
  left: -3em;
  height: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  border-top-color: rgba(43, 51, 63, 0.7);
}

.vjs-menu-button-popup .vjs-menu .vjs-menu-content {
  background-color: #2B333F;
  background-color: rgba(43, 51, 63, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 1.5em;
  max-height: 15em;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

**My CSS override**

```
 .vjs-menu-button-popup .vjs-menu {
      width: 20em;
      left: 1em;
 }
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fit-content` should work if the 100% width is unset on `.vjs-menu-content`

```css
.vjs-chapters-button.vjs-menu-button-popup .vjs-menu {
  width: fit-content;
}

.vjs-chapters-button.vjs-menu-button-popup .vjs-menu .vjs-menu-content {
  width: unset;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! – the `unset` property by itself worked but not with the `fit-content` prop.